# How to toggle text in progressive disclosure script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small progressive disclosure ("text expand and collapse") but the toggle text doesn't change. Works like this: ( and I didn't write it)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.view').hide();
    $('div.slide').toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).siblings('div.view').fadeIn('slow');
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).siblings('div.view').fadeOut('fast');
            return false;
        }
    );
});
```

I want to change the "more..." text toggle string to "less..." dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.view').hide();
    $('div.slide').toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).text('less...').siblings('div.view').fadeIn('slow');
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).text('more...').siblings('div.view').fadeOut('fast');
        }
    );
});
```

It's important to stick with `this` in the toggle, otherwise you're changing the text for *all* of the
`<div class="slide">` elements, not just the one you're dealing with.

Comment: @verlager - Welcome :)  Be sure to accept whichever answer you end up using on your questions :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're trying to do.  Please let me know if I'm not and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Here's my very simple markup...

```
<div class="slide">more...</div>
<div class="view">
<span>This is some stuff!</span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

and the script...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.view').hide();
    $('div.slide').toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).siblings('div.view').fadeIn('slow');
            $(this).text("less...");  //change the inner text of the DIV
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).siblings('div.view').fadeOut('fast');
            $(this).text("more...");  //change the inner text of the DIV
            return false;
        }
    );
});​
```

This will change the text in the `DIV` as soon as the `div` is clicked.

If you want to wait until the hidden `DIV` is shown to change the text, use this script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.view').hide();
    $('div.slide').toggle(
        function() {
                $(this).siblings('div.view').fadeIn('slow',
                  function() {
                    $("div.slide").text("less...")  //change the inner text after the animation is complete
                  });
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).siblings('div.view').fadeOut('fast', 
                   function() {                                                        
                      $("div.slide").text("more...");  //change the inner text after the animation is complete
                   });
            return false;
        }
    );
});​
```

Comment: This would change the text of *all* slide elements, you need to reference the one clicked, e.g. `this` in the click handler functions :)